# Mock webclient to call external api in Junit integration testing

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, junit-jupiter

I'm writing integration testing using **@EmbeddedPostgres**. I want mock webclient with response.
below is my method.

```
import org.springframework.http.client.reactive.ReactorClientHttpConnector;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;
import reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient;

@Service
public class TranslateApiConnector {
public JsonNode translateApi(TranslationInput translationInput) {

  HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create();
  ReactorClientHttpConnector connector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient);
  
   WebClient webclient = WebClient.builder().clientConnector(connector).baseUrl("baseUri").build();
   return webclient.post()
          .uri("uri")
          .body(Mono.just(translationInput),TranslationInput.class).exchange()
          .flatMap(clientResponse->clientResponse.bodyToMono(JsonNode.class)).block();
}
};
```

For above webclient method I need to mock webclient .How to write test case to call external api.
Here is my test method

```
@EmbeddedPostgres
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@Sql("/scripts/metadata.sql")
class TestApi {

    @Autowired
    private final TranslateApiConnector translateApiConnector;

   @Test
   voidTestConnector(){
      TranslationInput translationInput = TranslationInput.builder().input("test").build()

     ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
     JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree("{outputs: [{outputs: "test"}]}")
     
      Mockito.when(webClient.post().uri("uri").body(Mono.just(translaionInput),TranslationInput.class)
     .exchange()
     .flatMap(clientResponse -> 
      clientResponse.bodyToMono(JsonNode.class)).block()).thenReturn(jsonNode);

   Mockito.verify(translateApiConnector).translateApi(translationInput);
}}
```

Comment: reactive wiremock is your friend: 
https://www.sudoinit5.com/post/spring-boot-testing-consumer/